# How to remove invalid svn property

Tags: svn

I recently migrated sections of an old repository to a new one using `svnadmin` dump/load and `svndumpfilter2.py`.  Some of these sections were copied from another location, so the dump included several entries like:

```
K 126
Properties on '<repo/path>':
V 0
```

Everything imported ok, but this property is causing problems in the client, since the property key contains invalid symbols.  (I've tried `Linux 1.7.8`, `TortoiseSVN 1.7.X`, `1.8.X` and a few other windows clients)

Using `1.7.X (Linux/Tortoise)`, I can checkout, but can't view in the repo browser, or reverse-merge, or remove the property (Server sent unexpected return value (`400 Bad Request`) in response to `PROPPATCH`).

(Using `1.8.X`, I can view in the repo browser, but can't checkout.)

I have tried removing the property from the server version files, but this breaks the checkout (Could not read chunk size: connection was closed).  I expect there's an md5 that needs updating, but I could not see any directly associated with the property.

So...  Is there any way I can force removal of this property, or must I delete and re-migrate (this time including the copy source)?

Or...  Is there a way I can update the server version files to remove the property?

**Update:**

I wrote a script to mask out the rogue property with xxx, then verify and update checksums.  Didn't work (got "invalid chunk size" in client), so in the end I had to delete and re-import.

Lesson learnt - Don't use svndumpfilter2.py - Ever.  Always use the original svndumpfilter and include all required copy sources.